# Tippecanone & Mapbox - loosing details in a specific zoom level

Tags: mapbox, layer, tippecanoe

I render tiles for mapbox with tippecanone.

I want to use it to represent buildings. Unfortunately, the buildings lose the structure at zoom level 14 in Mapbox. I have already tried various options with tippecaone. Neither did it.

Info:

- Geojson file is 720mb in size

Used tippecanoe statement:

```
tippecanoe -d16 -r0 -z20 -o tiles.mbtiles tiles.geojson
```

[image: Map with Zoom level]